# Rails console slow tab completion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, irb

Running arch, when developing rails the console's tab completion for everything is incredibly slow. Even if the list it returns is inherently small.

User.n  for instance shouldn't return a horrid number of options, but it will basically halt for upwards of 20 seconds before doing anything. Behavior repeats on every attempt. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: have you installed any new gem ?

Comment: No, I don't recall a specific gem setting off this state of affairs. Should I comment them out 1 by 1?

Comment: What might be a tactic for seeing what call it is making that's locking it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the following lines from the file `/etc/profile`:

`PATH="$PATH:$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin"
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH`

And adding the following to ~/.profile 
`# make rails gems work 
PATH="$PATH:$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin"
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem`